# HTML element using a css :root variable to define color no longer updates dynamically after a javascrip function sets the :root variable

Tags: html, css, dynamic, browser, root

`CSS`

```
:root {
    --TAB00_COLOR: #FF5555;
 }

#L00    { background-color : var( --TAB00_COLOR ); }
#D01_00 { border-color     : var( --TAB00_COLOR ); }
#box_00 { background-color : var( --TAB00_COLOR ); }
hr.P00  { color            : var( --TAB00_COLOR ); }
pre.P00 { color            : var( --TAB00_COLOR ); }
th.P00  { border-color     : var( --TAB00_COLOR ); }
```

`JavaScript`

```
var r  = document.querySelector(':root');
var rs = getComputedStyle(r);

function change_the_color( hex_color ){
    r.style.setProperty( '--TAB00_COLOR' , hex_color );
}

function page_defaults(){
    document.getElementById("L00").style.background = rs.getPropertyValue('--TAB00_COLOR');
}
```

`HTML`

```
...
<script src="../../myJavaScriptFile.js"></script>
<body onload="page_defaults()" spellcheck="false">

<div class="slider_b">
    <input type="range" oninput="slider_00()" min="0" max="255" value="128" orient="vertical">
    <input type="range" oninput="slider_01()" min="0" max="255" value="128" orient="vertical">
    <input type="range" oninput="slider_02()" min="0" max="255" value="128" orient="vertical">
</div>

<label id="L00">LABEL00</label>
```

`SYNOPSIS`

I am musing FireFox 104.0 (64-bit) on Ubuntu Linux.

I am creating a web page ( on my hard drive...) that has a set of 11 tabs across the top.

There are 11 tabs , and I need to preset them to a initial state.  That initial state is the background color of the tab , the top , left , and right border color of the tab , and the bottom border of the tab.  These change depending on which tab is selected.  That is why I am trying to preset the tabs state with the page_defaults() function.

There is a range slider calling the function 'change_the_color()'.  It's purpose is to retrieve the hex value stored in the --TAB00_COLOR variable from the :root of CSS and convert it to RGB , modify it , convert it back to a HEX value , and set the the CSS --TAB00_COLOR variable to this new value.  This part works.

When this page loads , I can move the range sliders , and most of the HTML elements that are coded with the CSS variable --TAB00_COLOR dynamically change color in the browser window.  The only element that will not dynamically update is the L00 element ( which is the only one being directly changed by a document.getElementById("L00").style.background command ) in the function 'page_defaults()'.  If I remove that command from the function page_defaults , the label background changes with the rest , but I cannot preset my tabs state to initial.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Perhaps you could put up a complete runnable snippet so we can see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Where do you update rs?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
var r  = document.querySelector(':root');
var rs = getComputedStyle(r);

function change_the_color( hex_color ){
    r.style.setProperty( '--TAB00_COLOR' , hex_color );
}

function page_defaults(){
    document.getElementById("L00").style.background = rs.getPropertyValue('--TAB00_COLOR');
}
```

to this

```
function change_the_color( hex_color ){
    var r  = document.querySelector(':root');
    var rs = getComputedStyle(r);
    r.style.setProperty( '--TAB00_COLOR' , hex_color );
}

function page_defaults(){
    document.getElementById("L00").style.background = rs.getPropertyValue('--TAB00_COLOR');
}
```

alternatively change this

```
<script src="../../myJavaScriptFile.js"></script>
```

to this

```
<script src="../../myJavaScriptFile.js" defer></script>
```

Your function change_the_color() fails because the script is running before the DOM is loaded and the variables r and rs can't be instantiated because it can't find the root element.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think what is happening here is that:  r.style.setProperty( '--TAB00_COLOR' , hex_color ); is setting an inline style on the HTML.  This takes a higher priority over the reference to the :root variable , and therefore no longer tracks with the changes to that variable.